# How could it be true that T(n) = θ(1) + 2T(n/2) + θ(n) + θ(1) = 2T(n/2) + θ(n)?

Tags: time-complexity

I have a question about Time Complexity of this pseudo code.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gW8oo.png)

as following,

> T(n) = θ(1) + 2T(n/2) + θ(n) + θ(1)

> = 2T(n/2) + θ(n)

Can you explain me why these two 'θ(1)' are ignored in second equation?

Is it because meaningless comparing to 'θ(n)'?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not related to programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are constant and not going to change based on the value of n

Comment: This information can be provided under the comments section

Comment: To comment on question, 50 reputation score is required